# GPO to lock workstation after it is idle for X minutes without forcing a specific screensaver

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, windows

I'm trying to lock XP workstations after a period of inactivity via GPO.  From what I can tell, one of the requirements is that a screensaver must be set.  It appears that the only way to force the screensaver is to force a specific screensaver.  I'd rather just set a default screensaver to use when a different one has not been specifically selected on the client while also removing the ability on the client to opt-out of a screensaver.

Basically, I don't care what screensaver is running, as long as there is one running.  Is that possible?

Comment: Keep in mind that your users will always have the ability to select "none" as their screensaver and void your GPO.  In my environment, I had to select a default screensaver for everyone and disallow them changing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my 2008r2 DC, under User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Personalization I can select Enable Screen Saver, Password Protect Screen Saver, and Screen Saver Timeout without specifying a screensaver itself.  Force Specific Screen Saver is different.

Comment: The key was "enable screen saver".  It confused me because the description talks about needing to set a screensaver executable for it to work.

Answer (score 8):

In order to lock a workstation after X minutes, you should just need to set the three options below.  This will not require configuring a specific screensaver.
[image: GPO Settings]

Comment: My answer looks drab and unfulfilling in comparison to your pretty graphics.

Comment: Haha, I didn't feel like typing out the policy names.

Comment: heh, that was kind of a pain ;) Lots of alt-tab and minimizing.